# Print stdout to terminal and use for another command as stdin

Tags: bash

I want to make the stdout of a command visible on the terminal but also use it as stdin for another command without many workarounds i.e. creating files in between.

This obviously doesn't print the `stdout` to the terminal.

```
command1 > command2
```

With `tee` I would need to create a file in between, are there any other ways?

Comment: `> command2` I thin you meant `|`.

Answer (score 2):

So redirect a command to a file that outputs to the terminal.

```
command1 | tee /dev/stderr | command2

command1 | tee /dev/tty | command2

exec 3>&1
command1 | tee >(cat >&3) | command2
command1 | tee /dev/fd/3 | command2

{ command1 | tee /dev/fd/3 | command2; } 3>&1
```

etc. I typically use `tee /dev/stderr` to debug pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to print the output of `command1` on the screen, please try:

```
command1 | tee >(command2)
```

which distributes the output of `command1` to both the terminal and the stdin for `command2`.